# How to extract text line by line from Pdf in Python?

Tags: python

I am not getting any solution for this we have option available for extracting whole text using `Pypdf` but I want to extract text line by line. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I am trying this but it is giving the whole text. i want to extract line by line text.                                                                                                    
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\new.pdf','rb') 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)         
text = str(pageObj.extractText( ))

Comment: Put your code in the question so it's properly formatted and readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu, you could do something like:

```
$ less <file_name>.pdf >op.txt
```

and first redirect the text in the pdf to a text file and then read it line by line using the Python code:

```
f=open("op.txt",'r')

for line in f:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    print(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: While less can automatically call some converters (such as perhaps pdftotext from [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/)), it is not a converter itself. This is quite likely to just copy the pdf.